# If $|G|<\infty$ and $H\leq G$ is such that $[G: H]=2$ then $|x^G|=|x^H|$ or $|x^H|=\frac{1}{2}|x^G|$ for all $x\in H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ with index $2$, that is, $[G: H]=2$. Recall that $$C_H(x)=H\cap C_G(x), $$ where $C_G(x)=\{g\in G: gx=xg\}$.

How can I use the second isomorphism theorem to show that if $x\in H$ then: $$|x^G|=|x^H|\quad \textrm{or}\ |x^H|=\frac{1}{2}|x^G|?$$

**Sketch:**

Some facts:

**(i)** Since $[G: H]=2$ we have $H$ is a normal subgroup of $H$ (that is a condition to use the second isomorphism theorem).

**(ii)** I also know $|x^G|=[G: C_G(x)]$ as well as $|x^H|=[H: C_H(x)]$.

I guess I should split the problem into two cases if $x=e$ or $x\neq e$. If $x=e$ then $|x^G|=|x^H|$ clearly holds. As to $x\neq e$ I don't know what happens.

**Obs:** If the second identity holds we have:
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle |x^H|=\frac{1}{2}|x^G|&\Leftrightarrow [H: C_H(x)]=\frac{1}{2}[G: C_G(x)]\\
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{|H|}{|C_H(x)|}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}\\
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{|G|}{|H|}=2\frac{|C_G(x)|}{|C_H(x)|}\\
&\Leftrightarrow |C_G(x)|=|C_H(x)|.
\end{align*}

So it would suffice showing $|C_G(x)|=|C_H(x)|$, but it is strange for if $|C_G(x)|=|C_H(x)|$ then $C_G(x)=C_H(x)$ once $C_H(x)\subseteq C_G(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is enough to show that $C_G(x)=C_H(x)$ or $|C_G(x):C_H(x)|=2$.

$|C_G(x):C_H(x)|=|C_G(x)/C_G(x)\cap H|=|H.C_G(x):H|$ if $H$ contains $C_G(x)$ then the index is 1 otherwise $H.C_G(x)=G$ so the result is $2$.

Comment: why does $HC_G(x)=G$ hold in the second case? What I was thinking is, if $H$ does not contain $C_G(x)$ there exists $g\in C_G(x)$ such that $g\not\in H$ hence $G=H\cup gH$ (disjoint union). Therefore, given $a\in G$ then $a\in H$ or $a\in gH\in C_G(X)H=HC_G(x)$ but we might have $a\in H$..

Comment: @PtF: In a more clear way, H must be normal as it has index 2 so $HC_G(x)$ is a group containing H and becaus of the index; $HC_G(x)=G$.

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula combined with your first equality to determine what $[C_G(x):C_H(x)]$ could be.

Comment: Why the delete vote?